# Integrating an additive character over a local field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, haar-measure, automorphic-forms

Let $F$ be a non-Archimedean local field, $\psi$ a non-trivial additive character of $F$. Let $\mathfrak{o}$ be the ring of integers of $F$, and $\mathfrak{p}$ be the maximal ideal of $F$. Endow $F$ with a Haar measure (possibly normalized so that $\mu(\mathfrak{o}) = 1$).

I want to show that
$$ \int_{\mathfrak{p}^{-1}-\mathfrak{o}} \psi(-x) \ dx = -1 $$
and
$$ \int_{\mathfrak{p}^{-(k+1)}-\mathfrak{p}^{-k}} \psi(-x) \ dx = 0 $$
for all $k \geq 1$.

This feels like it's in the style of when you sum over all the non-trivial roots of unity, you get $1$. But I can't quite seem to translate this intuition into a proof. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

This integral shows up in Bump's *Automorphic forms and representations*, Ch. 4.6 p. 499.

Edit 1: I should mention that $\psi$ is trivial on $\mathfrak{o}$, and the codomain of $\psi$ seems to be $\mathbb{C}^\times$, the multiplicative group.

Comment: Your intuition is good: consider the stability of those various sets (you're integrating over) under units of the form $1+\mathfrak p^n$...

Comment: See the first section of Ralf Schmidt's paper on local newforms for $\mathrm{GL}_2$.

Comment: @paulgarrett Thanks for the reply -- I found a solution (posted below) which seems unrelated to your hint; can you elaborate more on how you thought about approaching this?

Comment: @klein4, your computation below is very efficient for the case at hand, but there is a device already used by Siegel 80+ years ago, though not in the terms I'll use: various integrals are over sets acted-upon by $U=1+\mathfrak p$ and similar smaller unit groups, so break up into $U$-orbits. The exponential map gives an isomorphism of $\mathfrak p$ to $U$, for odd $\mathfrak p$. On the orbit of $\pi^{-2}$, for example, $\psi((1+\pi x)\pi^{-2})=\psi(\pi^{-2})\cdot \psi(x\pi^{-1})$, so integrates to $0$ in $x$, because it's a non-trivial character. But, here, your induction is simpler. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\psi$ is trivial on $\mathfrak{o}$, we have
$$ \int_{\mathfrak{o}}\psi(-x)\ dx = \mu(\mathfrak{o}) = 1. $$
Since $\psi$ is non-trivial on the additive group $\mathfrak{p}^{-1}$, by the orthogonality of characters, we have that the pairing of $\psi(-x)$ with the trivial character on $\mathfrak{p}^{-1}$ is 0, and hence
$$ 0 = \int_{\mathfrak{p}^{-1}}\psi(-x)\ dx = \int_{\mathfrak{p}^{-1}-\mathfrak{o}}\psi(-x)\ dx + \int_{\mathfrak{o}}\psi(-x)\ dx = \int_{\mathfrak{p}^{-1}-\mathfrak{o}}\psi(-x)\ dx + 1. $$
A similar argument holds by induction to the additive groups $\mathfrak{p}^{-k}$.